# making LWP Useragent faster

Tags: perl, lwp, lwp-useragent

I need to perform a large number of HTTP post requests, and ignore the response. I am currently doing this using LWP::UserAgent. It seems to run somewhat slow though I am not sure if it is waiting for a response or what, is there anyway to speed it up and possibly just ignore the responses?

Comment: I don't know `LWP::UserAgent` that well, but have you tried setting the `max_size` to a low number? Perhaps the transfer is interrupted once the `max_size` is reached?

Answer (score 4):

bigian's answer is probably the best for this, but another way to speed things up is to use LWP::ConnCache to allow LWP to re-use existing connections rather than build a new connection for every request.

Enabling it is this simple if you're pounding on just one site --

```
my $conn_cache = LWP::ConnCache->new;
$conn_cache->total_capacity([1]) ;
$ua->conn_cache($conn_cache) ;
```

I've found this to double the speed of some operations on http site, and more than double it for https sites.

Answer (score 2):

LWP::Parallel

http://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Parallel

"Introduction

ParallelUserAgent is an extension to the existing libwww module. It allows you to take a list of URLs (it currently supports HTTP, FTP, and FILE URLs. HTTPS might work, too) and connect to all of them *in parallel*, then wait for the results to come in."

It's great, it's worked *wonders* for me...